# Update database with big CSV

Tags: php, sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I need every day update ~ 10.000 items in my MySql. I have upload a CSV file and try to update my database data. I am forking with two field. My problem is that works but in some time I get 504 Gateway Time-out and my upload is not able to finish the process.

here is my code

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"])){
        //      
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/upload/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
    $file_path="".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/upload/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]."";

    $file=file_get_contents("".$file_path."");
    $file=iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8",$file);
    file_put_contents("".$file_path."",$file);

if(!setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8')) setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8'); if(setlocale(LC_ALL, 0) == 'C') die('       (ru_RU.utf8, en_US.utf8)');
    if (($handle_f = fopen($file_path, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
        //   csv
        while (($data_f = fgetcsv($handle_f,99999,";"))!== FALSE) {
            //   ean13 
            $sql="SELECT id_product FROM ps_product WHERE reference = '".$data_f[0]."'";
            $id_product = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql,0);  

            //   ,    
            if ($id_product) {      
                $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE `ps_product` SET `quantity` ='".$data_f[1]."' WHERE `reference`='".$data_f[0]."'");
                echo "<p style='color:green'>Items<b>".$data_f[0]."</b> updated</p>";
            } else{
                echo "<p style='color:red  '>Items<b>".$data_f[0]."</b> not found</p>";
            }
        }
      echo "<b>Update is complited</b>";  

    }else{
        echo "Can`t open imported file";
    }
}else{
    echo '
    <h2>Quantity update:</h2>
    <form action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="file" name="filename"><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Load"><br>
    </form>
    ';
}
```

Now I split in excel for many files with ~ 1000 per fail and update database. It takes some time. Can you give me an idea, or maybe I have some error in my code? Update using ajax as I think will not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`504 Bad Gateway Timeout` is when your gateway/proxy server did not get a `timely response` from your processing server. In such cases, even if the processing server does finish all the updates, since it did not send any messages to your proxy to let it know that processing was still going on, the proxy closes the connection.

Using ajax for updates is not a very good idea in this case. However there is an `ajax design pattern` called the `heartbeat pattern` which can help you out. The basic idea is this:

1. You make a normal call to the processing page to start the CSV update
2. Additionally you set a javascript timer in your page which makes an ajax call to a server page every X minutes
3. The server responds with a simple message. Can be just a single character even
4. Your client side ajax can ignore this message, or print it or whatever
5. After X minutes the same process happens.
6. In the meantime the CSV processing you initiated in step one is still continuing

This `continuous message request and response` is called a `heartbeat`. It helps in keeping the `connection alive` while your server processing takes place. Once the server processing is over and you get a confirmation, you can kill the timer and close the connection as needed.

Of course on the processing server side, you can do additional things like `increase timeout lenght`, `add database indexes` etc to make sure that a `php process timeout` does not take place.

Note however that the process timeout is different from a Gateway timeout.

Comment: also I have an idea to split data by 1000 and upload it. I think it is not impossible to tell php close query after 1000 line and start new

Comment: You can think of creating a mechanism such that php executes 1000 lines and sends response to client. When client receives response, it again calls the same script which does the next 1000 and responds again. This way, user only need to click button/start request once, and the processing will continue in batches seamlessly.

Comment: Raidenace, so if I will do my upload in json, updae 1000 number and receive with json last insert number and continue wrom this part, json make in recursion, will it be separete queries? not one big, if yes then I think it will helps, also if make recursive in php will it work or it will be still one big query ?

Comment: Yes, it will be queries of 1000 each time. However you will also need to make sure that you handle issues like rollbacks in case one of the iteration fails. But yeah, it will not be one big, instead multiples of 1000s or whatever else number you choose to run in each batch

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on reference? If you don't it'll take a long time for each update.

Also, you have some MAJOR SQL injection issues, and mysql in depreciated, switch to mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the need to load large CSVs into MySQL and have found the best solution is to create a table that can hold the raw CSV data. I make the table with the same fields as the CSV then do a bulk import by using `LOAD DATA`, which is fast and then I can perform necessary queries on the data using SQL.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$filename}' 
INTO TABLE {$table_name} 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Once you have the CSV data in a table, you can then simply run a query in blocks (LIMIT and OFFSET) Psudeo code e.g.

```
DEFINE("BLOCK_SIZE",100);

// Get the total rows in CSV table so when can divide into blocks
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  * 
FROM   my_csv_table
LIMIT  1;

$total_rows = SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

for($counter = 0; $counter < $total_rows; $counter += BLOCK_SIZE)
{

    SELECT * 
    FROM   my_csv_table
    LIMIT  BLOCK_SIZE
    OFFSET $loop_counter;

    foreach $row 
    {

        // UPDATE YOUR REAL TABLE IF MATCHED

    }

}
```